# Why does '.CODE' have to be inserted before 'main PROC' only?

Tags: function, assembly

I am learning assembly language and had a question on syntax of procedure.
(I am using VS 2012).

For main procedure, if the line 'main PROC'  was inserted before '.data', the error would occur.

```
 .data

 .code    
 main Proc

 ;some code

 main ENDP

 local1 Proc
 .data
 .code
 ret
 .local1 ENDP
 END main
```

But for other local procedure under the main, it works fine with '.data' after the declaration of the procedure.

Could someone explain to me why?

p.s. Also is assembly lanaugage unpopular? I have learned little java and c++ and compare to them, there are much less discussion and searches on google.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question,  but you should place all procedures in `.code` sections.

Comment: Assembly language has been someone special purpose for quite some time. That purpose being low level routines where speed and memory consumption are extremely critical, or access to hardware features is possible but less practical with C or other popular embedded languages. So in short, you don't see a lot of it. And to your original question, as Jester says: code has to go into the code space, and `.code` designates code space. So the start of your proc must occur after `.code`, by definition.

Comment: I should add that particularly in the embedded systems world, even if you're programming in a higher level language like C++, understanding what happens at the assembly language level is essential in being able to solve a variety of problems that may arise in that world.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine assembler as a machine which reads input source and writes (emits) to two output channels: one for executable code and another one for data.
Segment-switch directives **.data** and **.code** tell assembler where it should write the emitted information. 
Using directive **.data** you actually command your assembler: stop emitting to whichever output segment was current at the moment, switch to the segment .data and continue writing to this segment at the next free space (origin), where you left it the last time it was active.

Alternation between .code and .data segment in source text is good for readability of the program, it allows to keep code procedures close to the global data it operates with. On the other hand, when the compiled program is loaded in memory, all procedures have to be linked together in one code segment and all data are kept together in data segment. Operating system usually does not allow to execute any instruction from segments marked as "data", and to write any data to segment marked as "code". That is why it is programmer's responsibility to switch to **.code** before any executable statement is emitted.